# How to get custom date format value from NGX-Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I m using NGX-Bootstrap for my angular6 project. I have reactive form and added datepicker to it and while returning the value from datepicker getting full format ex: "2018-11-07T05:12:35.000Z". But I want in MM-DD-YYYY.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before returning the date, convert the date format as the following:

```
let date = new Date(dateValue).toLocaleDateString();
```

then assign `date` to the form controller

Comment: Thanks for the genius answer mate. Cheers!

Comment: this will show mm/dd/yyyy formate is there any way in which we can store the date into db using bsDatepicker and getting value from db and show it in the same field like add then edit operations, when we edit it should again store it in the same format as in add operation

Answer (score 1):

to be more generic you can create a directive which returns the date in the format you want. for eg.

```
<input changeDateFormat type="text" placeholder="Datepicker" class="form-control" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue">

export class changeDateFormatDirective implements OnChanges {
@Input() bsValue: Date;
@Output() bsValueChange = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
//change Date format here, you can import format date from @angular/common
this.bsValueChange.emit(newDateFormat);
this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
  <input  bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'MM-DD-YYYY'}" >
```

Comment: The above line of code only to show the format of date in input tag. But while returning the value from input using reactive form it is returning 2018-11-07T05:12:35.000Z. 

it is not returning the value as dateInputFormat.

for temporary fix i m getting value using javascript document and updating the react form data.

Comment: This config is about to change the date format inside the input field, not the actual output